# Plone: insert line between News items in Collection view

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3.   We have a folder called News containing News items.  In the folder, we have collection also called News.  The default view of the News folder is set to the News collection.   And in News collection, we set the default to Item: News and All Contents.   The end result is we get a page showing the five most recent News items when we click on the News folder with page numbers below linking to older News items.   The body of the News items is also displayed, but there is not line or border between each News items.

Question:  How can we configure Plone or Collection or News Items to automatically insert a horizontal line between each News item body when they are displayed in the Collection view?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Comment: What specifically can you not accomplish here with CSS and Firebug to inspect what you have?  I do not want to downvote this question in case I do not understand the intent or need completely, but CSS is the simple and I think obvious way to solve this problem.  This is a styling problem only, no?

Comment: no bacause you've to add an <hr /> tag, not just change the bottom border of a div. The question is about customizing the news content object template. The news view is not customizable TTW, z3c.jbot seems the real option here.

Comment: Thank you Yuri.  I guess the News view is indeed not customizable without using third party tools.

Comment: The All Contents template is an FS page template, not a view: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/folder_full_view.pt

Answer (score 1):

You can have this behaviour with a simple mix of maquillage and stylesheets :) 
..You can custumize the appearance of your Plone site in 3 ways:

- edit the main plone's [stylesheet in a skin layer in the zmi](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/buildingblocks/skin/style-sheets/css/css-quick-start) (fastest and worst method)
- create your own plone [theme with a plone package](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference) (old fashioned but evergreen)
- create your own plone theme with [Diazo](http://diazo.org/) and its corresponding Plone integration [plone.app.theming](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming) (latest trend and quite easy to start with if you are not yet a Plone developer)

Comment: Thank you Giacomo Spettoli for the suggestions but we want to customize the News view only.  As Yuri pointed out above, it is not customizable.

Comment: Well this is not exact..I can agree that there's no solution out-of-the-box but it *can* be customized in a few ways with a very little coding. A simple way could be to use Diazo and an `append` rule (but this is not the only one).

Comment: -We've decided to use the first method: edit the main plone's stylesheet in a skin layer in the zmi (fastest and worst method).  This is what we did.  It turns out that we could use the h2.header style is quite unique to News pages.   We went to ZMI.  portal_css and set to development mode.  portal_skins and select portal_styles and then ploneCustom.css - customize and enter this CSS code:  h2.headline
{
border-style:ridge none none none;
}
and then save, upload.  After that, a line will appear about the heading of each News article.